# Visibility of an overriden component

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

In [Binding References to Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#component-references) there's an example which I find confusing:

```
<xsl:package name="P" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:use-package name="Q">
    <xsl:override>
      <xsl:variable name="C" visibility="private" select="$xsl:original + 3"/>
    </xsl:override>
  </xsl:use-package>

  <xsl:template name="T" visibility="public">
    <xsl:value-of select="$A"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:package>
```

Then it says:

> The visibility is changed according to the rules in 3.5.3.2 Accepting
>   Components: in particular, visibility="private" changes to
>   visibility="hidden".

Why do you need to specify `private` to change the visibility to `hidden`? I would expect that, since you are overriding the component, the original overridden component is automatically hidden, and that all symbolic references in both using and used packages refer to the new overriding component.

> Component Cp is the overriding component. Its properties are exactly
>   as if it were declared as a top-level component in P (outside the
>   xsl:use-package element)...

That means that `C` is visible to any using package, yet it's marked as `private`.

Comment: Did you check whether that is actually the case, i.e. whether the overridden variable `Cp` is visible in a third package? _"Its properties are exactly as if it were declared as a top-level component"_ does not necessarily mean that this variable would be public, in my opinion. It only means that the same rules are applied in both contexts.

Comment: @MathiasMüller No I haven't checked, I'm just trying to understand the spec at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 components named C. C(Q) is the component as declared in Q, and is public within Q. C(PQ) is the "copy" of this component within P, and is hidden within P because an overriding declaration exists; it cannot be called using the name C, but only using the name xsl:original. C(P) is the overriding component in P. It is private within P because the overriding declaration has `visibility="private"`. I think the table below has an error where it says that C(P) is public.

Please feel free to ask these questions directly of the WG by raising them on the W3C bugzilla, even if they are simply questions of clarification. All feedback is welcome: indeed, W3C monitors the amount of feedback.

== PS ==

The XSL WG (which happens to be meeting this week) reviewed this and agreed that the visibility of C(P) should be private (*). See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=29468

Note that the reference to 3.5.3.2 Accepting Components is not directly relevant, because the rules there talk about what happens in the absence of an xsl:override element.

Thanks for your feedback.

(*): I've corrected this. I originally wrote "public".

Comment: Thanks Michael. One last question. The default visibility of components is private, that includes overridden components? If C(P) didn't include   `visibility="private"` it would be public?

Comment: No, `visibility="private"` is the default (except for xsl:param)